# How do CSV to XML converter

Tags: php, xml, csv, converters

How make this:

[image: The picture below shows about what I mean:]

One line from the file one loop and inserting data into variables. Since the xml file will be a bit more complex. (More branches)

Comment: So too I have no idea how to solve

Comment: Please tell me that's not your personal music collection! ;)

Comment: This was the only example. I worked it already has loaded a csv file into an array using a loop later typed into the template and save the file :)

Answer (score 0):

I have such a thing but, as used in this template?

```
<?php

$csv = array();
$file = fopen('faktury.csv', 'r');



function csv_to_array($filename='faktury.csv', $delimiter=';')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

$xml = csv_to_array();

echo'<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo'</pre>';
?>
```